# How to set the binding.UpdateSourceTrigger of DataGridTextColumn in AutoGeneratingColumn event of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to set the UpdateSourceTrigger of a DataGridTextColumn binding to "LostFocus" from the code-behind in the AutoGeneratingColumn event. The default behavior is that the source is only updated when the row loses focus, but I need it to update when the cell loses focus.

Here is my attempt:

```
    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
            //my attempt to get cell to update on cell lost-focus, rather than row lost-focus
            Binding newBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName);
            newBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
            (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding = newBinding;
    }
```

This does not seem to be working because the source is still only being updated once the row loses focus.

Note: I am aware this is usually done in the XAML in the column defintion, but I cannot put it there because my columns are being dynamically generated at run-time.

Comment: I tried your code, and the binding updates the viewmodel property when I tab into the next cell, rather than when I tab out of the whole row. I think that's what you're trying to do. If I set it to `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`, I get the expected flurry of property updates on every keystroke.

Comment: What data structure are you using as your itemssource to the datagrid? I am using a data table, and I'm not seeing the update when the trigger is set to either LostFocus or PropertyChanged -- only when the row loses focus still.

Comment: I had a collection of POCO objects. I'm setting up a DataTable test case now. How are you checking for the value being updated?

Comment: I was looking at the DataTable.Rows[0].ItemsArray in the ViewModel. I saw that if I accessed the same DataTable from the code behind before the ViewModel code executed, the values were updating as expected. But, when the DataTable property was later accessed in the ViewModel code, the old values were showing. I think my issue might be more complex than I originally thought. I will have to look into it more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmmm. I handled DataGrid.CellEditEnding. I've found that with your AutoGeneratingColumn handler, if I tab out of the edited cell and look at the DataTable in the viewmodel, the value in the datatable is already updated. If I commit the edit by pressing the return key, it isn't already updated. In CellEditEnding, I can check if `e.EditingElement is TextBox`, and if it is, call `(e.EditingElement as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();` -- and that updates the binding in the Return case. FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed a boolean property to be changed immediatly after clicking in DataGrid, and the following code worked:

```
private void ExcludeTable_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn column && column.Binding is System.Windows.Data.Binding binding)
    {
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```